# Nodejs Promises unusual behaviour with exec

Tags: node.js

i am executing the following code in nodejs and want an output like this :
and want an output like this

```
Running Code
Compiling Code
Executing Code
Done Execution
Done Compiling
Done everything
```

But the output is like this :

```
Running Code
Compiling Code
Executing Code
Done Execution
Done Compiling
Done everything
```

This is a strange behaviour :/

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var Q = require('q');

var script_sh = 'bash -c' + ' "echo "hegr" ;"';

function compile(req, res) {

  var deferred = Q.defer();

  console.log('Compiling Code');

  exec(script_sh, function puts(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err || stderr) {
      console.log('Error While Compiling');
      console.log(err);
      res.send(stderr || err );
      return deferred.reject(err);

    }
    console.log('Done Compiling');
    return deferred.resolve();
  });
  return  deferred.promise;
}

function execute(req, res) {
  console.log('Executing Code');

  var deferred = Q.defer();

  exec(script_sh, function puts(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err || stderr) {
      console.log('Error While Execution');
      console.log(err || stderr);
      res.send(err);
      return deferred.reject(err || stderr);
    }
    console.log('Done Execution');
    return deferred.resolve();
  });
  return  deferred.promise;
}

function run_code(req,res) {

  console.log('Running Code');

  compile(req,res)
    .then(execute(req,res))
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Done everything');
    }).fail(function (error) {
      error.status = 412;
      return ;
    });
};

module.exports = run_code;
(function() {
  if (require.main == module) {
    var req = console.log;
    var res = console.log;
    res.send = console.log;
    run_code(req,res);
  }
}());
```

Comment: Wait, what exactly is the difference between expected and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not waiting for `compile` to resolve before invoking `execute`, but rather using the return value of `execute` as an argument to `then`, which happens to be a resolved `Promise`;

```
 compile(req,res)
    .then(execute(req,res))
```

The argument to `then` is evaluated when the body of the function `run_code` is evaluated, not when `compile` resolves. To wait for `compile` to resolve before executing `execute`, use:

`compile(req, res)
    .then(execute.bind(null, req, res));`

`execute.bind(null, req, res)` will return a pre-bound function that will execute after `compile` resolves.

Alternatively,

`compile(req, res)
    .then(function () {
         return execute(req, res);
     });`